# Which character is this (red suit, white hood and cape, villainy-looking)?

Tags: comics, character-identification, super-hero

I came across this guy while watching one of these nonsensical videos on YouTube with my nephew.
I tried to find some clues and browsed through Marvel and DC lists, but cannot seem to find him.
Any help would be appreciated, since 3yo are relentless in their pursuit of knowledge.

[image: whodat]

Comment: Have you got a link to the video? I'm 99% sure it is Shazam per my answer but not sure where from. The full context might help even if it is just a fan creation.

Comment: There you go, but I think you nailed it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwFbt5w98Eg&t=70

Comment: Shazam or Captain Marvel (the name was changed for trademark reasons).

Comment: Not su much "Villain-y' as "not-so-great CGI".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like that is supposed to be Captain Marvel/Shazam from DC:

[image: Shazam with white hood, red clothes, white cape and lightning bolt]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

More specifically this is [Shazam from the *Injustice: Gods Among Us*](https://injustice.fandom.com/wiki/Shazam) game and the "Injustice: Earth One" universe. You can compare to the video below found by @Valorum:

Comment: More specifically it's the New 52 variant of Shazam from the PS3 game Gods Among Us; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySbEhNKk6ug

Comment: @Valorum Ah good find was having trouble working out where specifically he was from. Didn't think to check the games, was looking through the cartoons.